# Checking if a file is readable and exists in one if condition: if [[ -r -f "/file.png" ]] 

Tags: bash, if-statement, debian

I was writing an if statement which checked if a file is readable and exists by doing the following:

```
if [[ -r "$upFN" && -f "$upFN" ]]; then
....
fi
```

Then I thought, surly you can make this smaller, something maybe like this:

```
if [[ -r -f "$upFN" ]]; then
....
fi
```

But this doesn't work, it returns errors:

```
./ftp.sh: line 72: syntax error in conditional expression
./ftp.sh: line 72: syntax error near `"$upFN"'
./ftp.sh: line 72: `if [[ -r -f "$upFN" ]]; then'
```

Comment: `-f` is for files, `-d` is for directories.

Comment: Oops, didn't mean to have /folder/ in the title :P

Answer (score 13, accepted):

AFAICT, there is no way to combine them further.  As a portability note, `[[ expr ]]` is less portable than `[ expr ]` or `test expr`.  The C-style `&&` and `||` are only included in bash so you might want to consider using the POSIX syntax of `-a` for *and* and `-o` for *or*.  Personally, I prefer using `test expr` since it is very explicit.  Many shells (bash included) include a builtin for it so you do not have to worry about process creation overhead.

In any case, I would rewrite your test as:

```
if test -r "$upFN" -a -f "$upFN"
then
  ...
fi
```

That syntax will work in traditional Bourne shell, Korn shell, and Bash.  You can use the `[` syntax portably just as well.

Comment: I always thought that [[ expr ]] was safer then [ expr ] when using variables in them. I wasn't aware that || and && only work in bash, will use -a -o as you suggested from now on. Cheers

Comment: So when should Bash-specific features be used?

Answer (score 4):

Is there ever a case where a file would be readable but it *doesn't* exist? Don't bother checking for existence when readability will tell you all you need.

Comment: `-r` checks for readability and `-f` checks for a *file* that exists.  The `-r` portion could succeed for a directory and the `-f` will fail.  The post didn't mention that `-f` requires the item to be a file.  `-e` checks for existence.

Comment: I thought that -f and -r will never succeeded if the file doesn't exist, never heard of the -e, will have to check the man.

Comment: I just realized, that there is a case where `-r <file>` is true and `-f <file> && -r <file>` is not: for a readable directory.

Comment: Yes, @Oliv. That's what D. Shawley pointed out — the distinction between `-f` and `-e`. I don't think it's an important distinction in this case because I think Mint believed `-f` to be acting like `-e` all along. That is, I think the original use of `-f` was a mistake.

Comment: I took it to mean that the file might exist, but you may not have read permissions.  Ex.: `/var/log/secure`.