# How to loop a shell script across a specific file in all directories?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed, sh

Shell Scripting sed Errors:

Cannot view /home/xx/htdocs/*/modules/forms/int.php

/bin/rm: cannot remove `/home/xx/htdocs/tmp.26758': No such file or directory

I am getting an error in my shell script. I am not sure if this for loop will work, it is intended to climb a large directory tree of PHP files and prepend a functions in every int.php file with a little validation. Don't ask me why this wasn't centralized/OO but it wasn't. I copied the script as best I could from here: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-replace-string-words-in-many-files/

```
#!/bin/bash
OLD="public function displayFunction(\$int)\n{"
NEW="public function displayFunction(\$int)\n{if(empty(\$int) || !is_numeric(\$int)){return '<p>Invalid ID.</p>';}"
DPATH="/home/xx/htdocs/*/modules/forms/int.php"
BPATH="/home/xx/htdocs/BAK/"
TFILE="/home/xx/htdocs/tmp.$$"
[ ! -d $BPATH ] && mkdir -p $BPATH || :
for f in $DPATH
do 
 if [ -f $f -a -r $f ]; then
   /bin/cp -f $f $BPATH
   sed "s/$OLD/$NEW/g" "$f" > $TFILE && mv $TFILE "$f"
 else
  echo "Error: Cannot view  ${f}"
 fi
done
/bin/rm $TFILE
```

Do wildcards like this even work? Can I check in every subdirectory across a tree like this? Do I need to precode an array and loop over that? How would I go about doing this?

Also is, the $ in the PHP code breaking the script at all?

I am terribly confused.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want `init.php` and not `int.php` as you have written? Else, either turn on the shell debugging feature with `set -vx` (or `set -x`), to see what values are being used for each variable OR add an `echo f=$f` right after the `for f in $DPATH`. I would expect `*` to expand if there are files `module/forms/int.php` under the subdirs of `.../htdocs`.  Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Problems in your code

- You cannot use sed to replace multiple lines this way.
- you are using `/` in OLD which is used in a `s///` sed command. This won't work
- `[ ! -d $BPATH ] && mkdir -p $BPATH || :` is horrible. use `mkdir -p "$bpath" 2>/dev/null`
- Yes, wildcards like this will work but **only because your string has no spaces**
- Doube-quote your variables, or your code will be very dangerous
- Single quote your strings or you won't understand what you are escaping
- Do not use capital variable names, you could accidentally replace a bash inner variable
- do not rm a file that does not exist
- **Your backups will be overwritten** as all files are named int.php

Assuming you are using GNU sed, I'm not used to other sed flavors.
If you are not using GNU sed, replacing the `\n` with a newline (inside the string) **should** work.

## Fixed Code

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
old='public function displayFunction(\$int)\n{'
old=${old//,/\\,} # escaping eventual commas
# the \$ is for escaping the sed-special meaning of $ in the search field
new='public function displayFunction($int)\n{if(empty($int) || !is_numeric($int)){return "<p>Invalid ID.</p>";}\n'
new=${new//,/\\,} # escaping eventual commas
dpath='/home/xx/htdocs/*/modules/forms/int.php'
for f in $dpath; do 
    [ -r "$f" ]; then
        sed -i.bak ':a;N;$!ba;'"s,$old,$new,g" "$f"
    else
       echo "Error: Cannot view  $f" >&2
    fi
done
```

## Links

- [Replace newline in sed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1252191/4486184)
- [Inplace replace with sed with a backup](http://alvinalexander.com/linux-unix/sed-edit-files-in-place-make-backup-copy)
- [Using a different sed substitution separator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6449741/4486184)
- [Existency not necessary if readable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4653852/4486184)
- [Bash search and replace inside a variable](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#search_and_replace)
- [Bash guide](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide)

Comment: Thanks for the very thorough answer. I ended up writing a php script that implemented a reflector class, but thank you kindly stranger :)